# How to download entire site content in Appfog?

Tags: wordpress, paas, appfog

I had created a wordpress app in appfog, but the "download source code" function in Appfog didn't allow me to download the entire website content, for example, the files under the `wp-content/uploads/` can't be included. The support in appfog reply is all below:

> When you do an 'af pull' command this is going to pull the last
>   staged or pushed copy of the application and does not pull what is
>   live on the server. We do recommend for user uploads and static media
>   content especially for Wordpress that a CDN like Amazon S3 is used to
>   store those files. This would be so that you have direct access to
>   them via the CDN, they are served away from the application for better
>   performance, and they will not go away on restart of the application
>   with the ephemeral file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you cannot bulk download the file system or uploads from AppFog without a tool inside the app that exposes the filesystem. You are much better off storing Wordpress uploads in S3 buckets using a WP plugin like [WP2Cloud](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp2cloud-wordpress-to-cloud/) with your AppFog hosted app. Amazon S3 is a fast, durable, and inexpensive cloud file store and is highly recommend for WP uploads.

More information about using S3 with AppFog: http://blog.appfog.com/how-to-use-amazon-s3-for-persistent-file-storage-on-appfog/